# WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable - chromedriver 2.30

Tags: selenium

```
In [12]: from selenium import webdriver

In [13]: chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

In [14]: chrome_options.add_argument('--no_sandbox')

In [15]: chrome_options.add_argument('--privileged')

In [16]: browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/jeremie/Downloads/chromedriver', chrome_o
    ...: ptions=chrome_options)

In [17]: browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
```

When I ran the last line, I got

```
WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.81)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 4.8.0-32-generic x86_64)
```

I tried to change another version of the chromedriver, but I got other issues. I tried to fix my problem with other question from SE, but nothing solved my problem. What could I do to fix that problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. check you have the execution right on the chrome bin. Is possbile the chrome browser installed not by your account?
2. Give a try not to add arguments to chromeOptions
3. Give a try with lower down your chromedriver version

Comment: running the RemoteWebDriver only passing the Uri and empty options object (new ChromeOptions()) helped. It ran fine and when I've gone back to my "normal" options, it just executed okay. It's hard to say what was the actual cause!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not `setProperty()`

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for seeing the `WebDriverException` as `chrome not reachable`.

1. First and foremost, we have to ensure that our `Selenium` version, `chromedriver` version and `Chrome` version are compatible. You can find the compatibility information on the `Downloads` page of [**`ChromeDriver`**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) individually for each releases.
2. Consider removing all the dangling `chromedriver` instances from you system. If possible make a system restart.
3. Periodically run `CCleaner` to wipe away all the previous execution leftovers.
4. When you initialized the `webdriver` instance, you mentioned:

   ```
   browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/jeremie/Downloads/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
   ```

   Instead, while we mention the absolute path of the `chromedriver` binary we must also provide the argument `executable_path`. So we may need to change to:

   ```
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path='/home/jeremie/Downloads/chromedriver')
   driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
   ```